# R nls2 function - Error in result[[which.min(ss)]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, nls

I'm for 2 days struggling to do a multiple regression.
Here's what I have at this moment:

```
y<- c(-0.3902,  0.5277,  0.4357, -0.1888, -6.7422,  0.3797, -0.5141,      NA, -1.2423,  5.6756, -0.5352,
-0.2379,      NA,  0.4270,      NA,      NA,      NA,      NA,      NA,      NA, -1.1185,  0.0594,
 0.8280,      NA,  1.8387, -3.1469,-1.6212, -0.8400,      NA ,     NA,      NA, -0.7291,  2.0888)
x<- c( 0.07712829, 0.07038519, 0.08875312, 0.08235028, 0.10874493, 0.09713412, 0.11821937, 0.12796526,
0.12159038, 0.08520884, 0.07046089, 0.07417249, 0.07507544, 0.11416440, 0.09955467, 0.06688244,
0.06871298, 0.06187514, 0.12293434, 0.07864503, 0.12417404, 0.08600490, 0.10745128, 0.12277381,
0.12952106, 0.09144677, 0.09034708, 0.08039892, 0.07856194, 0.07864304, 0.10883127, 0.10690687,
0.11617899)

f1<- y ~ ((a*b)/(a+b)+x)

st1 <- expand.grid(a = seq(0, 1000, len = 10),
                   b = seq(0, 800, len = 10))

o<-nls2(f1,
        start = st1,
        algorithm = "brute-force")
```

And the result is

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>    Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
>   Error in result[[which.min(ss)]] : 
>    attempt to select less than one element in get1index

I've tried with

````
st2<- data.frame(a = c(0,1000), b = c(0, 800))
o<-nls2(f1,
        start = st2,
        algorithm = "brute-force")```
````

getting

> Error in result[[which.min(ss)]] : 
>    attempt to select less than one element in get1index

I have no idea what the value for a can be, which also makes it difficult to give a starting value. I have to apply the equation to multiple datasets (here I just give the smaller one for example).

Any tips on how to get this done? 
Perhaps using a different package for multiple regression instead of nls2?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is not identifiable.  The outer parentheses make no difference so we can write your model equivalently as:

```
y ~ (a*b)/(a+b) + x
```

and the first term is just some constant so cannot be a function of two parameters.

Also note that the right hand side is NaN if a=b=0.

Perhaps you intended `f2` shown below.  Have also changed 0 to 1 in the lower limits to avoid the NaN situation.

```
st2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1000), b = c(1, 800))
f2 <- y ~ (a*b) / (a+b+x)
nls2(f2, start = st2, algorithm = "brute-force")
```

### Added

From the comments `y ~ (a*b)/(a+b) + x` was actually your intention so in that case we can make it identifiable and so amendable to modeling using:

```
 f3 <- y ~ A + x
 nls(f3, start = list(A = 1))
```

This model is so simple that we can alternately calculate the optimum value of A directly as `mean(y - x, na.rm = TRUE)`.  Now choose `a` (or `b`) arbitrarily and solve `A = a * b / (a + b)` for `b` (or `a`) noting that if we take reciporocals of both sides we have `1/A = 1/a + 1/b`, i.e. `A` is half the harmonic mean of `a` and `b`.

If you do want to use nls (even though it's easy to do without it) so that you don't have to solve for a or b then try this:

```
o <- order(x)
dd <- na.omit(data.frame(x, y)[o, ])
b <- 800
f1 <- y ~ (a*b)/(a+b) + x
fm <- nls(f1, dd, start = list(a = 1))
plot(y ~ x, dd)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, dd, col = "red")
```

Comment: G. Grothendieck my equation was correct, despite the extra (). y ~ (a*b)/(a+b) + x. I tried different combinations of starting values to no success so far.

Comment: See Added section.

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck. I gave an arbitrary b=800 and the result doesn't make sense to me. At this point I'm probably not thinking straight anymore.  Nonlinear regression model
  model: y - x ~ (a * 800)/(a + 800)
   data: <environment>
      a 
-0.1431 
 residual sum-of-squares: 102.9

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.501e-09

Comment: As mentioned this is so simple you don't even need nls for this, mean is sufficient to calculate A and then you can solve for a by hand; however, if you prefer to let nls do the work I have added some code at the end.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated. I just randomly divided the data set for a cross validation and it's working.